# Flutter web control main AutoRoute from nested route

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I use AutoRoute navigation (https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) in flutter web project.
Is it possible to control AutoRoute routes from another AutoRoute routes?

[image]

- I need change (main) route from nested route.

  Example: From **Navigation Page 2** I would like to open **About
  Screen**
- And in the opposite way. I need push nested route from another (main) route (And remove before route from navigation stack).

  Example: From **Login Screen** I would like to open **Navigation Page 3**, and remove **Login Screen** from navigation stack

Answer (score 0):

> Example: From Navigation Page 2 I would like to open About Screen

```
context.router.replaceAll([const AboutRoute()]);
```

> Example: From Login Screen I would like to open Navigation Page 3, and
> remove Login Screen from navigation stack

```
context.router.navigate(const HomeRouter(children: [{... your nested stack... }]));
```